# Localhost pointing to different codeFolder locations 

Tags: coldfusion, dreamweaver, fusebox

WINDOWS XP PROFESSIONAL/coldfusion/Dreamweaver/Fusebox-3

I have the same CF-8 code in two places

```
* folder A:- c:\Coldfusion8\wwwroot\BootsmanCode\code
* folder B:- c:\wwwroot\BootsmanCode\code    

          Local:- http://127.0.0.1:8500/BootsmanCode/
          http://localhost:8500/BootsmanCode/
```

ISSUE:- I am making my code changes in  "folder B", testing it on http://localhost:8500.
When I go home and use VPN, I cannot see these code changes when I call http://localhost:8500 from folder B
Then when I use http://localhost:8500/, with code from folder A,  I am able to see the code changes.

So the URL seems to be magically pointing to different folders at at diffent time.

Any correction to this please let me know?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you get at what URL? Do you mean that `localhost` gives you Folder B, and `127.0.0.1` gives you Folder A? Gonna need more info about exactly what's happening, and what you *want* to happen.

Answer (score 0):

Would need more detail for a more definitive answer, I'd be happy to take a closer look. But some things I would look at/ask/suggest include:

1. If you're using IIS, do you have any bindings/host headers that route the request from one folder to another? Following up on VAS's comment (are we talking about a 127.0.0.1 vs. localhost showing different results issue?)
2. From home, when you VPN... are you accessing http://localhost... from your PC? Or are you remote-desktopping to your PC at work and doing it from there? Localhost is relative to the machine that you're on.
3. Make sure CF has template caching at 0.
4. Make sure your browser isn't caching the site.